# python boto3 dynamodb filter expression boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Using boto3 for Python to write a dynamodb query that will filter the result. One of the fields I need to filter on is a boolean. In PartiQL, it works fine. In boto3, I can't seem to get filter to work with a boolean.

```
FilterExpression=Attr('name').ne('bob_smith') & (Attr('darn_it').not_exists() | Attr('darn_it').eq(False))
```

I am using the or `|` to see if the attribute exists for the record, or is False. I've tested with out the `.not_exists()` method as well, but can't seem to get the `.eq(BOOL)` to work. Maybe I am using the wrong method for boolean?